# Add jquery plugin to Symfony 2.1 project

Tags: jquery-plugins, symfony, assets, assetic

How can i add some jQuery plugin to a Symfony 2.1 project?

I install all frontend assets with the composer so all plugins are stored in the **Symfony/vendor** directory.

I can specify JS-file to load in a template like this:

```
{% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output='js/compiled/plugins.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/author/plugin1/plugin.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/author/plugin2/plugin.js'
    '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/author/plugin3/plugin.js'
%}
```

And after calling:

```
php ./app/console assetic:dump ...
```

All specified files will be compiled and placed under the **Symfony/web** directory.

But what if some plugin requires more than just a single JS or CSS file? What if it needs to load some images, styles or scripts dynamically from inside a plugin directory (which is out of web-server's document root)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a slight problem with Assetic. Combining the css files to one with `assetic:dump` can break the plugin's internal directory structure. It is pretty much up to the plugin's own architecture how it survives from the asset dumping.

One option [is to use `assets:install` command](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig) that copies or symlinks the asset files from Bundle/Resources/public/ folder to web/bundles/ directory.

What I usually do is to place the external library files (css, js and images) directly under web/ in proper subfolders. When css and js files are combined and placed to the web root (with `assetic:dump`) all the plugin files are found from the proper subfolders. This method works also when working in CDN environment. However, this is not the most elegant solution and it slightly violates the idea that all Bundles (or plugins) should stay separated from each other.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's against best practices to put plugins inside a bundles and i don't really like idea to copy plugin assets in the **web** directory manually as it will be hard to manage and update. I just don't see any other options though.